# Why does Hibernate create a Join Table by default for @OneToMany?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, relational-database, libraries

`@OneToMany` annotation, by default, creates a join table, unless the `mappedBy` element is specified.

What is the reason for this behaviour? For example, with the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    // ...
    @OneToMany
    private List<UserDocument> documents;
    // ...
}

@Entity
public class UserDocument {
    // ...
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    // ...
}
```

For the `User` entity, why doesn't Hibernate simply:

1. Find the field with type `User` in `UserDocument` by doing reflection on `UserDocument` entity.
2. Infer the value of `mappedBy` for the `@OneToMany` annotation by itself?

What is the reason for not doing this and generating a join table as the default behaviour? Why is Hibernate (or JPA) is designed this way?

Comment: Hi. What does "Infer the value of mappedBy for the @OneToMany annotation" mean? Also, it is not clear when you are talking about Hibernate "doing" in the sense of creating a design vs "doing" in the sense of calculating given an entity (id), ie join vs "find"/"infer". Please edit to be more clear. Use enough words & sentences to refer to everything clearly. PS The answer is going to involve you distinguishing between abstract operations on tables vs how (combinations of) those are implemented in particular cases. Also, read the documenation re mapping models per annotations to tables.

Comment: You mean why does the JPA SPEC mandate it as the DEFAULT for 1-N? Because it does. Read the JPA spec. That is nothing to do with the "mappedBy". It is due to the absence of `@JoinColumn`.

Comment: @philipxy I am talking about the design decisions. Why Hibernate (or rather, JPA) is designed this way.

Comment: @DN1 Yes, why does the JPA spec mandate this?

Comment: Why not? It has to pick using fk or using join table. So it picks a default. Subjective

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple reason behind this is that Hibernate cannot known for sure that a filed of type `User` inside of `UserDocument` is corresponding to the specific `User`-`UserDocument` relation. Without a `mappedBy` property, Hibernate can only create a join table or insert a generated column in `UserDocument` table. However, the latter alters data model and introduces more problem than it may resolve ( distinguish generated or declared column; table schema mismatch model class; etc.). Thus Hibernate use a join table to store the mapping.

For example, if you want to track the last one who modifies a document, you may need another many-to-one relation in `UserDocument`. This cannot be infered and resolved just using reflection.

```
@Entity
public class UserDocument {
    // ...
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    private User lastModifiedBy;
    // ...
}
```